# Return a statement based on the type of the input(float/int/str)

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, types, casting

I am a beginner in coding python and I stumbled upon an issue with a particular exercise. This exercise involves asking an input string from the user and to print out the length of the string. If the user types an int, it should say "You can not calculate the length of an int" and if the user enters a float it should say, "You can not calculate the length of an int". Here is my code.

```
def string_length(mystring):
     if mystring.isdigit():
         return "You can not calculate that length!"
     if isinstance(mystring,float):
         return "You can not calculate that length!"
     else:
         return len(mystring)

mystring = input("Enter some random string ")
print(string_length(mystring))
```

This does not print out any error but the function itself does not work when I enter in a float as an input. I have tried

```
type(mystring) == int/float
```

but it is not working. How can i modify my code to solve this problem?

Comment: A better approach is to raise a `ValueError` or `TypeError`. See for yourself: `len(3.14)` and `len(3)`

Answer (score 3):

The misunderstanding is that the built-in `input` gives a type *dependent on the value input*. This isn't true. It **always** gives string / `str` output in Python 3.x.

One way you can *test* for a potentially non-string input is to *try* converting to `float`. If successful, `print` your error message. If not successful, compute and `return` the length of the string:

```
def string_length(mystring):
    try:
        float(mystring)
        return 'You cannot calculate the length of a number'
    except ValueError:
        return len(mystring)

mystring = input("Enter some random string ")
print(string_length(mystring))
```